# LoadError: 'Cannot load such file' using gems via rbenv, brew & bundler with MacOS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, bundler, rbenv, vendor

I seem to have a lot of problems with using rbenv, bundler & brew. It seems to me as if my system always loads the gems into `vendor/bundle` while trying to call the file from another directory but fail to load. As this error happens a couple of times also in other projects, I assume it is not gem-specific/related but maybe I am wrong? I would be happy, if you could point me to the right direction as I read a couple of issues regarding this (e.g. incorrect ruby install, brew loads from `/usr/bin/ruby` which is not there, activate symlink, being in wrong directory, etc.)  but couldn't solve it until now. :( Thank you.

**Here are the utitilies & software I use:**

- MacOS X 10.9.5 on MacBookPro
- Sublime 2 Editor
- iTerm 2 (Build 2.1.4)
- rbenv 0.4.0
- Bundler 1.10.6
- Homebrew 0.9.5

**Ruby Installations via rbenv:**

```
* 2.0.0-p645
* 2.2.1(globally set by /Users/myusername/.rbenv/version)
* 2.2.2
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby '2.2.1'

gem "chronic", "~> 0.9.1"
```

**Gemlock file:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    chronic (0.9.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  chronic (~> 0.9.1)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

**Local Gems List**

```
actionmailer (4.2.3)
actionpack (4.2.3)
actionview (4.2.3)
activejob (4.2.3)
activemodel (4.2.3)
activerecord (4.2.3)
activesupport (4.2.3)
arel (6.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6, 1.10.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.7.0, 5.4.3)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
power_assert (0.2.3, 0.2.2)
psych (2.0.13, 2.0.8)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.3)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.3)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.8)
sprockets (3.2.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.10)
test-unit (3.1.2, 3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

**Steps:**

- Step 1: mkdir chronic
- Step 2: cd chronic
- Step 3: touch gemfile
- Step 4: set in gemfile: gem "chronic", "~> 0.9.0"
- Step 5: bundle install
- Step 6. touch filename.rb
- Step 7. ruby filename.rb
- Step 8: cat ~/.bash_profile
- Step 9: cat ~/.bashrc
- Step 10: check for possible conflicts with previously installed rvm
- Step 11: check for rvm rest
- Step 12: Steps I already tried

**Step 5: Output in iTerm:**

➜  chronic git:(master) ✗ bundle install

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/bundle: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: no such file or directory
Resolving dependencies...
Using chronic 0.9.1
Using bundler 1.10.6
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

**Step 7: a) FINAL ERROR Output in iTerm using Ruby '2.2.1' locally & globally:**

➜  chronic git:(master) ✗ ruby filename.rb

```
   /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext  /kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- chronic (LoadError)
    from /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from filename.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

**Step 7: b) FINAL ERROR Output in iTerm using Ruby '2.0.0-p645' locally & globally:**

➜  chronic git:(master) ✗ ruby filename.rb

```
/Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- chronic (LoadError)
    from /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from filename.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

**Step 8: Output in iTerm:**

➜  ~  cat ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PS1="\u@\h\w$"
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias ll='ls -l'

function prompt {
  local BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
  local BLACKBOLD="\[\033[1;30m\]"
  local RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
  local REDBOLD="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local GREENBOLD="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
  local YELLOWBOLD="\[\033[1;33m\]"
  local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  local BLUEBOLD="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  local PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
  local PURPLEBOLD="\[\033[1;35m\]"
  local CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
  local CYANBOLD="\[\033[1;36m\]"
  local WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
  local WHITEBOLD="\[\033[1;37m\]"
  local RESETCOLOR="\[\e[00m\]"

  export PS1=\n$RED\u $PURPLE@ $GREEN\w $RESETCOLOR$GREENBOLD\$(git branch 2> /dev/null)\n $BLUE[\#] → $RESETCOLOR"
  export PS2=" | → $RESETCOLOR"
}

prompt
```

**Step 9: Output in iTerm:**

➜  ~  cat ~/.bashrc

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

alias be='bundle exec'
alias s='be rails server'
alias r='be rake'

export NVM_DIR="/Users/myusername/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

**Step 10: Because I had rvm before and removed it (correctly hopefully), I also checked for rvm by following:**

➜  ~  find rvm

```
find: rvm: No such file or directory
```

➜  ~  which rvm

```
rvm not found
```

➜  ~  rvm -v

```
zsh: command not found: rvm
```

**Step 11: Find Ruby**

```
➜  ~  which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
➜  ~  whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

**Step 12: Things I already tried:**
- gem update --system
- rbenv rehash (after ruby version switches)
- bundle update 
- brew update
- xcode-select --all